# How do I grab the parent component from a nested child component in Stencil.js?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I tried using `closest()` and I tried with `parentElement`, but it's not working. I either get `null` or I get the parent up until the shadowRoot, and then it's `null` again.

```
<ifx-sidebar>
      <ifx-sidebar-item active="false">
        Header Section
        <ifx-sidebar-item active="false" onclick="handleSidebarPage(event)">
          Second layer
          <ifx-sidebar-item  active="true">
          3rd layer Menu Item 
          </ifx-sidebar-item>
        </ifx-sidebar-item>
      </ifx-sidebar-item>
</ifx-sidebar>
```

Inside the `ifx-sidebar-item` component, I have `this.el.closest('ifx-sidebar')`, and I keep getting `null`. Why!? Why am I not getting the parent `ifx-sidebar`? `parentElement` only works up until the `shadowRoot`, and then it's `null` again. How do I get the `ifx-sidebar`!?
`this.el` inside the clicked component shows the current `ifx-sidebar-item` component.

Comment: Either ``getRootNode()`` or "walk up the DOM" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520554/custom-element-getrootnode-closest-function-crossing-multiple-parent-shadowd

Comment: Don't know you intention nor your code; but does ``ifx-sidebar-item`` really need a shadowDOM?

Comment: Child components shouldn't need to know about or access parent components - that's more than likely a design flaw. Parents should listen to events from children to be updated about activity and changes.

Comment: @G.Tranter I have a sidebar that contains sidebar-items. I have created a Prop for "active" so the users can manually turn a sidebar-item into active or false. There can be only one 'active', and for that reason, I want to implement a logic that automatically turns all items into active false except the current active one, so for that reason, I tried to grab the parent from inside the current active item in order to then query all the nested items, and turn them into false. So, would you then suggest I instead emit the current active one into the parent, and implement the logic there?

Comment: @G.Tranter I was wondering if I should even implement this logic, but if I don't, then it would be up to the users to do it themselves, and I want to make it easier for them.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to emit the sidebar-item component itself, so users can change the 'active' prop on it easier?

Comment: Yes, Events prevent tight coupling, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545953/advanced-search-in-javascript/69575222#69575222

Comment: @happy_story Yes - implement the "control" logic in the parent. Your pattern is very similar to a radio-group radio-button pattern. The group/parent "manages" - the button/child simply emits a select/active event that the parent consumes.

Comment: Can you please help me with another thing. In my component, on load time, I inside each sidebar-item, I grab all the nested sidebar-item components, and append them into another <li> dropdown menu, and as a result, the DOM structure changes, and I can no longer use `parentElement` to grab their parent sidebar-item. So, do you think it would be a good solution if I instead emit the sidebar-item to the sidebar parent, grab it, find the parent of that particular sidebar-item, and then return it back to the sent sidebar-item via an event? Would that be a good idea or too convoluted?

Comment: For example. If you look at my code snippet above, imagine the 3rd layer component is clicked, we then emit that component all the way to the top `sidebar`, there, we find the parent of that emitted sidebar-item, i.e. the 2nd layer sidebar-item, and then we send it back to the clicked 3rd layer sidebar-item.

Comment: Don't use parentElement (inflexible/bad design). Off the top of my head - emit item event on item click and let immediate parent only handle it. If parent is "group" item, emit "group" event from parent, and so on until parent is sidebar. Parent item or sidebar should only need to manage immediate children, not nested (grand)children. You will need to stop propagation of child event at each parent to re-emit parent event so that grandparents don't receive multiple events on a single select. Parents just "unselect" other siblings. Unselect call on group calls unselect on all immediate children.